# IBM Worklight - Any advantages for when developing a Mobile web app?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-runtime

Going through the IBM Worklight product documentation,the product looks great for building hybrid or native applications. However for building mobile web (with responsive web design) what are the specific advantages one can get from worklight?

Comment: It's not going to be a native application with worklight, phonegap or titanium...

Answer (score 2):

For (the) Mobile Web (environment), I don't think that at this time there is much left.

However, you do still:

- get to use Worklight Adapters and its extensive integration abilities, which do make it easier to connect to various backends
- use Cordova to access some device native capabilities
- use the [WL Client JavaScript API](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.help.doc/apiref/r_wlclient_javascript_client_lib.html)

Comment: Worklight adapters assume web services available.In a scenario where web services are to be written (for the sole purpose of exposing it to device) can't we achieve the same with a simple REST based solution that can talk to back end systems and provide a simple api to the device?

Comment: Even in Hybrid apps you could also use AJAX instead of adapters... that's beside the point. The point is the (possibility of) ease of development with adapters. But that's, up to you.

Comment: thank you.So the main advantage are 1.ease of development 2. same code base can be easily converted to hybrid apps.Any specific advantage with respect to worklight server in terms of scalability etc?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question... is that in regards to the Mobile Web environment? I don't think it matters to the server... it's agnostic to the environments it supports, they are all the same for it.